# Salvar imagem no Firebird com C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, firebird-2.5

Criei um form para cadastro (`CRUD`) e necessito salvar a foto do produto ou pessoa para cada cadastro, até encontrei na Internet algumas coisas com `OpenDialog`, mas nada conclusivo com `Firebird`.

1. O campo para salvar foto é do tipo BLOB? Mas o que é o `Segment Size` e qual tamanho colocar?
2. Alguém pode me ajudar nesse código, e se posso determinar o tamanho do arquivo e também forçar como `JPG`, justamente para o banco não perder performance?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17350/Firebird-and-Images um código que pode ser utilizado como referencia

Comment: 1 - Se for um byte array sim. O segment size é o tamanho do segmento, quando você salva um arquivo ele divide ele em segmentos, se você não botar nada, o default é 80
2 - Mostra o código que já tem pra gente ver :D